Inequality involving a symmetric matrix and minors of an orthogonal matrix
Fix $n \geq 3$ and take any orthonormal vectors $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Let also $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ be a symmetric matrix with positive entries ($A_{ij} = A_{ji} > 0$). Is the following inequality true? $$\sum_{i<j}A_{ij}\begin{vmatrix}x_i & x_j \newline y_i & y_j \end{vmatrix}^2 \leq \sum_{i<j<k}\max(A_{ij},A_{ik},A_{jk})\begin{vmatrix}x_i & x_j & x_k \newline y_i & y_j & y_k \newline z_i & z_j & z_k \end{vmatrix}^2$$
For $n=3$ the proof is easy: The sum on the LHS has just three terms and one can simply write
$$A_{12}\begin{vmatrix}x_1 & x_2 \newline y_1 & y_2 \end{vmatrix}^2 + A_{13}\begin{vmatrix}x_1 & x_3 \newline y_1 & y_3 \end{vmatrix}^2 + A_{23}\begin{vmatrix}x_2 & x_3 \newline y_2 & y_3 \end{vmatrix}^2 \leq \max(A_{12},A_{13},A_{23})\Bigg(\begin{vmatrix}x_1 & x_2 \newline y_1 & y_2 \end{vmatrix}^2 + \begin{vmatrix}x_1 & x_3 \newline y_1 & y_3 \end{vmatrix}^2 + \begin{vmatrix}x_2 & x_3 \newline y_2 & y_3 \end{vmatrix}^2\Bigg) = \max(A_{12},A_{13},A_{23}) = RHS$$
Numerical experiments suggest that the inequality holds for $n>3$ as well, but how to prove it? Any hint would be much appreciated!

It seems that you asked a lot of questions like this involving minors of matrices. May I ask if they have any background? How do you come up with them?

(1/2) Long story short, I'm interested in showing that the map $D(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) = \sqrt{\sum_{i<j} d_{ij}^2|x_i y_j - x_j y_i|^2}$, where $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{C}^n$ are unit vectors (not necessarily orthogonal) and $(d_{ij})$ is an $n$-by-$n$ distance matrix, satisfies $D(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) \leq D(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{z}) + D(\mathbf{z},\mathbf{y})$. So far, we have managed to prove it in various special cases (including $n=3$), cf. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2312.02583.pdf Most of the inequalities I have been asking about have popped up while searching for a general proof.

(2/2) The current inequality (with $A_{ij} := d_{ij}$) turns out to be a necessary condition for our desired inequality to hold for $n>3$. At the same time, it looks as if it might appear also in other contexts that I am not aware of (especially that numerics suggests it is true for any symmetric positive-entried $(A_{ij})$, i.e. not just for distance matrices). In asking the current question I hope that someone might recognize this inequality or know how to prove it. This could offer a foothold on the main problem I am interested in.

Unfortunately I don't think MSE is a good place to ask about ongoing research... maybe move these questions to MO instead?

Will do, thanks! Although MSE did help me massively with a research question the other day.

Cross-posted on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/q/469781/116247.
